# webrequest service vs local database search

Tags: sql-server, httpwebrequest, windows-server-2008

I have an application that runs multiple threads where a part of the process involves making http post requests to a webservice where the parameters I submit are checked in a database whether it exists already and if not then inserted.

The database itself is hosted on the same server where the app runs. We originally had it hosted on a different server but it crashed, hardware failure..and was not able to handle all the requests I make per second.

Now I am getting server errors when making requests to the service and was wondering which approach would be more efficient and faster...and less error prone...

1. use the existing method of making requests to the service and work around the issue or
2. access the db locally myself and check the tables and do the inserts myself which will obviously slow down the process

I am trying to avoid issues here and the programmer that set up the service says he has done everything on his part and I should space out my requests more but I still do not see why all of a sudden I am getting primary key violation errors when prior to the move, if I sent a parameter that already exists in the table I would receive a set response  and not an internal server error.

Comment: You didn't mention the exact error that you are getting - I assume you are getting PK violation errors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Webservice requests are asynchronous, so you will not be able to account for the PK violation errors. There are various ways to handle the situation:

1. The webservice hosting code should be changed to handle the situation that when a PK exists, it should return the same response it gave when the first time that request was sent. The calling requests are separate, and on separate threads, and would never know that another request already inserted the same value. The whole point of WS is so that multiple requests can come in at the same time, from anywhere. The business logic should  handle that they come in at the same time.
2. Change your code to access the DB directly (as you mentioned). This will not make the process slower by any means (although work is involved upfront to change your code), since a WS request has to go over HTTP protocol, whereas from your code you will access directly via ADO or OLEDB provider that your code provides.
3. You could possibly queue up your requests, and then hit one by one, and not hit the next one until the one processing has received a response. I don't like this because its not scalable - defeats the purpose of a WS (but you may be stuck with this if the programmer doesn't change the WS code)

The solution suggested by the WS coder is ridiculous. There is no way to space out your requests so that it won't cause the PK violation. There is no way you can know which ones have already been inserted, or what other requests are already in process. Also, spacing out requests doesn't make the whole application scalable - your front end (or whatever else is waiting for the response) will end up waiting.

Comment: Maybe a hybrid of your #1 & #3... Upon submission, the requests are queued. The main web service thread spawns child threads to do the work. Each child thread is assigned a different item in the queue. The child thread processes its work and returns the result either as an update to the original queue or a new item on a response queue. Transaction isolation levels can be used to keep the child threads consistent. The queue management can be in the db (service broker). You could then control the throughput by limiting the number of child threads and choosing how often to check for results.

Comment: Yes, that will work (also requires some upfront work). Although queuing maybe the only option left, I am really not a fan in this case, because it becomes a bottleneck if the application gets a lot of hits - spawning child threads with a frequency as required by the application may not be able to be handled by the WS host - which is where I really think this should be handled...

Comment: And, of course, since Oded's application is on the same server as SQL, the resource usage would be even more important. Lastly, I totally agree with M.R. that "spacing out" the requests is a non-solution. The way I see it, you either tune things to avoid excessive contention or, if the workload is that severe, use a queue.